# void pointer to struct, element access using macros

Tags: c, pointers, macros, c-preprocessor, void

Given the following struct,

```
typedef struct tCard {
    CardClass class;
    void *proto;
} Card;

typedef struct tCardPath {
    PathType path_type;
    struct tPath path;
    Goal goal;
} CardPath;
```

Is it possible to access the element pointed by a pointer to struct (proto) using macros, like this?

```
((CardPath*)(trial[i].proto))->element1; // this works
CARD_PROP(trial[i], Path, element1); // the goal
```

I tried this, but this gives `error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token` when compiling,

```
#define PROTO(C) (C).proto
#define CARD_PROP(C, CARD, PROP) (((Card##CARD *)(PROTO(C)))->(PROP))
```

EDIT:
Tried this, still doesn't work

```
#define CARD_PROP(C, CARD, PROP) ((Card##CARD *)(PROTO(C))->PROP
```

Comment: Your new edited macro produces exactly `((CardPath *)((trial[i]).proto)->element1;`. Notice the 4 ( and the 3 )

Comment: May I ask why do this? Smells like an XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't put members of a struct in parentheses. Your macro expands to:

```
((CardPath*)(trial[i].proto))->(element1)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Which shouldn't have parentheses where I marked above.